# Missing passages on econometric formula

Tags: calculus

In the econometric lecture notes that i'm reading there is a passage for a PV model for the term structure of interest rate:

\begin{equation}
(1+R_t)^h=\Theta_t \prod_{j=0}^{h-1} (1+E_t r_{t+j}) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)
\end{equation}

became

\begin{equation}
R_t=\frac{1}{h}\sum_{j=0}^{h-1}E_t r_{t+j}+\theta_t \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)
\end{equation}

where $\theta_t=(\frac{1}{h})\log\Theta_t$.

Someone can please help me to understand the passages from (1) to (2).

Thanks

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from $$\begin{equation}
(1+R_t)^h=\Theta_t \prod_{j=0}^{h-1} (1+E_t r_{t+j})
\end{equation}$$ take the logarithms of both sides so $$h\log(1+R_t)=\log(\Theta_t)+ \sum_{j=0}^{h-1} \log(1+E_t r_{t+j})$$ and I suppose that the terms are small compared to $1$. So, remember that in such a case $\log(1+x)\approx x$. So,$$h R_t\approx \log(\Theta_t)+\sum_{j=0}^{h-1} E_t r_{t+j}$$

Comment: Seems to be the reason indeed, I face this often in that area.